# Google plus sign in : How to get the user email?

Tags: php, post

I'm using this code https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client the user-example.php in the examples folder, to make some tests on Google plus signin.

Everything worked well, except one thing. After the connection, i obtained this url :

```
http://MYURL/?code=4/vt_b0DsUU91UOYkB3ozIp-ZLITiL2irzaaUzyvtdph4.4gAL4kfDZGUVJvIeHux6iLafIxOglAI
```

My question is, where can i get the user email ?

Thanks

Comment: First of all, you should use a library, etc. for convenience. Furthermore the point of G+ signin is to hide that information from websites. It this allows users to remain anonymous. The URL however contains a token and depending on the access a user has given, you can access the email address.

Comment: What kind of library? And how do i get the email address ?

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR: Fully working solution: [Get Userinfo from Google OAuth 2.0 PHP API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14007560/get-userinfo-from-google-oauth-2-0-php-api)

You're using offline flow which is described in details here:  https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer#handlingtheresponse

At this point you got code.

`vt_b0DsUU91UOYkB3ozIp-ZLITiL2irzaaUzyvtdph4.4gAL4kfDZGUVJvIeHux6iLafIxOglAI`

This code needs to be exchanged for access_token.

Exchanging code for access token using Google Library: https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/blob/master/examples/user-example.php#L66

With access_token you can send api requests.