# Using google account for private website access

Tags: php, google-oauth, google-api-php-client, google-signin, google-account

Currently, the person I'm developing for uses google docs to display the website/files. Which can only be accessed via google accounts ending in a certain domain name. For example danny@webtest.com if it's a webtest google account then it can access it.

Now I'm creating them a website not linked to google. However, I still need this authentication process.

**Step One**
login page will be a simple "connect with google account"

**Step Two**
user is redirected to login to google, if they're already logged in then moves to next step.

**Step three** email address is crosschecked with my database, if there a session is made for the row id of that user, if not then it is added.

I'm trying to keep this as simple as possible, however I have no idea where or how to do step Two.

Comment: It seems like you're just trying to make a basic OAUTH2 authentication, look it up :)

Comment: @Welshboy I've yet to try anything, as I didn't know where to start. Anything I searched for google account authentication just lead me to google logins etc. However, I know what I'm doing after the fact I just couldn't figure out how to get the information to return so I can cross check it with my database.

Comment: added relevant tags for question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading the Wikipedia introduction mentioned by @Izzy, you can have a look [at google's Oauth2 introduction](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2) and then jump into [google's quick start sample app](https://developers.google.com/+/quickstart/php); it gives a fully working commented php app of using oauth 2.0 to authenticate with a google account and fetch user data.

The code in the example uses the package [google-api-php-client](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client.git) as well as a js library to reduce the boilerplate to simpler API calls. For the client/frontend side, javascript calls such as:

```
auth2.signIn().then(function(googleUser) {
  onSignInCallback(googleUser.getAuthResponse());
}, function(error) {
  alert(JSON.stringify(error, undefined, 2));
});
```

And on the server, php side:

```
$code = $request->getContent();
// Exchange the OAuth 2.0 authorization code for user credentials.
$client->authenticate($code);
$token = json_decode($client->getAccessToken());

// You can read the Google user ID in the ID token.
// "sub" represents the ID token subscriber which in our case
// is the user ID. This sample does not use the user ID.
$attributes = $client->verifyIdToken($token->id_token, CLIENT_ID)
    ->getAttributes();
$gplus_id = $attributes["payload"]["sub"];

// Store the token in the session for later use.
$app['session']->set('token', json_encode($token));
$response = 'Successfully connected with token: ' . print_r($token, true);
```

Please note that requesting an email address will require asking further the permission (named [`Authorization scopes`](https://developers.google.com/+/api/oauth#scopes)) from the client, as seen [in this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14007560/get-userinfo-from-google-oauth-2-0-php-api):

> `$client->setScopes(array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile'));`

You can then use any number of [APIs that expose userinfo.email](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=userinfo.email). One of these, `Google_Service_Oauth2`, has the helpful public method `userinfo`

```
$oauth2Service = new Google_Service_Oauth2(...);
$userinfo = $oauth2Service->userinfo;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [OAuth2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAuth). Google uses it for authentication process.

OAuth states for Open Authorization. OAuth is protocol which is designed to work with HTTP enabling access tokens to be issues to third-party clients by auth server, with approval action from user.

OAuth is starting to be deprecated, and all major companies are starting to use OAuth2 protocol which is improved version of OAuth, but unfortunately it is not backward compatible.

You can find several implementation in PHP like [this one](https://github.com/adoy/PHP-OAuth2).

Comment: Although you're not wrong, link only answers are discouraged. Bring some code into your answer. You should also discuss what OAuth2 is and what it does to OP and future readers. See: [How to write a good answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: @Izzy Thank you for your answer, I'll be sure to check it out.